# In R plotting keyword / word associations (findAssocs) with igraph on tdm or dtm in R?

Tags: r, plot, igraph, term-document-matrix

I'd like to create a [term network analysis plot](http://beyondvalence.blogspot.com/2014/05/text-mining-7-term-network-analysis.html) based on certain [word associations](http://beyondvalence.blogspot.com/2014/01/text-mining-4-performing-term.html) in R but I don't know how to go beyond plotting a entire Term Document Matrix:

```
# Network analysis
library(igraph)
# load tdm data

# create matrix
Neg.m <- as.matrix(Ntdm_nonsparse)

# to boolean matrix
Neg.m[Neg.m>=1] <- 1

# to term adjacency matrix
# %*% is product of 2 matrices
Neg.m2 <- Neg.m %*% t(Neg.m)
Neg.m2[5:10,5:10]

# build graph with igraph ####
library(igraph)
# build adjacency graph
Neg.g <- graph.adjacency(Neg.m2, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected")
# remove loops
Neg.g <- simplify(Neg.g)
# set labels and degrees of vertices
V(Neg.g)$label <- V(Neg.g)$name
V(Neg.g)$degree <- degree(Neg.g)

# plot layout fruchterman.reingold
layout1 <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(Neg.g)
plot(Neg.g, layout=layout1, vertex.size=20, 
     vertex.label.color="darkred")
```

Is there anyway to apply a word associations [network analysis plot](http://www.r-bloggers.com/igraph-and-structured-text-exploration/) to (as well as a general word associations [bar plot](http://beyondvalence.blogspot.com/2014/01/text-mining-4-performing-term.html)) the following `findAssocs` data for example?:

```
findAssocs(Ntdm, "verizon", .06)
$verizon
           att       switched         switch       wireless         basket         09mbps         16mbps 
          0.16           0.13           0.11           0.11           0.10           0.09           0.09 
        32mbps           4gbs           5gbs        cheaper            ima         landry          nudge 
          0.09           0.09           0.09           0.09           0.09           0.09           0.09 
         sears           wink      collapsed      expensive         sprint          -fine           -law 
          0.09           0.09           0.08           0.08           0.08           0.07           0.07 
         11yrs            380            980         alltel        callled         candle           cdma 
          0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07 
       concert    consequence    de-evolving          dimas          doria          fluke           left 
          0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07 
        london           lulz        lyingly           niet        outfits     pocketbook           puny 
          0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07 
     recentely         redraw    reinvesting      reservoir    satellite's         shrimp   stratosphere 
          0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07 
     strighten       switchig      switching        undergo     wheelchair wireless-never          worth 
          0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07           0.07 
          yeap           1994            299       cheapest           com'          comin        crushes 
          0.07           0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06 
  hhahahahahah          mache          metro      metro-nyc        must've         rising       sabotage 
          0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06           0.06 
wholeheartedly 
          0.06
```

In other words, I'd like to visualize the connections a specific keyword has with other keywords in R but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the example in ?word_network_plot (package qdap).